# Enable/disable selectInput based on value in another selectInput

Tags: shiny, shinyjs, disable, selectinput

In my shiny app, I need to disable selectInput Season and selectInput Mesh if the value selected for selectInput Species is "Kemps". Those same two selectInput objects should be enabled for any other species selection. I found some shinyjs code (https://towardsdatascience.com/heres-how-to-spice-up-your-shiny-app-84866ccb69dd) and adapted to my app but I am getting errors. I would appreciate any guidance. Thanks!

```
spp <- c("Atlantic Sturgeon","Green","Kemps")
seas <- c("Fall","Winter","Spring","Summer")
mus <- c("A","B","C","D","D1","D2","E")
meshes <- c("Large","Small")

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel(title=div(img(src="imgPS.png",height=75),"Protected Species Model")),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("species", "Protected Species", spp),
    selectInput("Season", "Season", seas),
      selectInput("MU", "Management Unit", mus),
      selectInput("Mesh", "Mesh Size", meshes),
      numericInput("trip", "n Trips", 1, min = 1),
      actionButton("btnEstTakes","Estimate Takes")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      h2("Predicted Takes"),
      textOutput("prediction_text")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$species, {
    if(input$species == "Kemps"){
      shinyjs::disable(id = "Season")
      shinyjs::disable(id = "Mesh")
    }
    else {
      shinyjs::enable(id = "Season")
      shinyjs::enable(id = "Mesh")
    }

  predict_df <- eventReactive(input$btnEstTakes, {
    
    # Validate the user input. I dont trust these people! :) 
    validate(need(input$species, "Please select a valid Species!"))
    validate(need(input$Season, "Please select a Season!"))
    validate(need(input$MU, "Please select a Management Unit!"))
    validate(need(input$Mesh, "Please select a Mesh Size!"))
    validate(need(input$trip > 0, "Enter a valid trip count!"))
    validate(need(input$species != "Atlantic Sturgeon" | (input$MU != "D1" & input$MU != "D2"),
    "Management Unit selection not valid for Atlantic Sturgeon"))
    validate(need(input$species != "Green" | input$MU != "D",
    "Management Unit selection not valid for Green"))
    validate(need(input$species != "Kemps" | (input$MU != "D" & input$MU != "D1"),
    "Management Unit selection not valid for Kemps"))

    ITPYear <- c(2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021)
    Species <- input$species
    Season <- input$Season
    MU <- input$MU
    Mesh <- input$Mesh
    LogEffort <- log(input$trip)
    
    # Create data set for Kemps
    df1 <- cbind(MU,LogEffort)
    df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)
    
    df1$Species <- Species
    df1$MU <- as.factor(df1$MU)
    df1$LogEffort <- as.double(df1$LogEffort)
    
    # Create data set for Atlantic Sturgeon and Green
    df2 <- cbind(Season,MU,Mesh,LogEffort)
    df2 <- as.data.frame(df2)

    df2 <- df2[rep(1,9),]
    df2 <- cbind(ITPYear,df2)

    df2$Species <- Species
    df2$ITPYear <- as.factor(df2$ITPYear)
    df2$Season <- as.factor(df2$Season)
    df2$MU <- as.factor(df2$MU)
    df2$Mesh <- as.factor(df2$Mesh)
    df2$LogEffort <- as.double(df2$LogEffort)

    df3 <- df2

    df4 <- cbind(Species,Season,MU,Mesh,LogEffort)
    df4 <- as.data.frame(df4)

    # Predict based on species selection
    if(Species=="Kemps"){
      df1$Prediction <- predict(mod.kemps,type="response", newdata=df1)
      df1$Live <- round(df1$Prediction * (1-kemps.dead), 0)
      df1$Dead <- round(df1$Prediction * (kemps.dead), 0)
    } else if(Species=="Green") {
    df2$Prediction <- predict(mod.green,type="response",newdata=df2)
    pred.use <- mean(df2$Prediction)
      df4$Live <- round(pred.use * (1-green.dead), 0)
      df4$Dead <- round(pred.use * (green.dead), 0)
    } else {
      df3$Prediction <- predict(mod.astg,type="response",newdata=df3)
      pred.use <- mean(df3$Prediction)
      df4$Live <- round(pred.use * (1-astg.dead), 0)
      df4$Dead <- round(pred.use * (astg.dead), 0)
    }
 
    df.pick <- cbind(Species,Season,MU,Mesh)
    df.pick <- as.data.frame(df.pick)

    if(Species=="Kemps"){
      df.pick$Live <- df1$Live
      df.pick$Dead <- df1$Dead
    } else {
      df.pick$Live <- df4$Live
      df.pick$Dead <- df4$Dead
    }

    df.use <- df.pick[,c('Species','Live', 'Dead')]
    return(df.use)
  })
  
  df <- reactive({
    predict_df()
  })
  
  output$prediction_text <- renderText({
    paste0("The model predicted ", df()$Live, " live ", df()$Species, " and ", df()$Dead, " dead ", " ", df()$Species, ".")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine if you enable {shinyjs} at beginning of `ui`:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  ...
```

(also close with `})` the observeEvent)

```
observeEvent(input$species, {
    if(input$species == "Kemps"){
      shinyjs::disable(id = "Season")
      shinyjs::disable(id = "Mesh")
    }
    else {
      shinyjs::enable(id = "Season")
      shinyjs::enable(id = "Mesh")
    }
})
```